# Get the line above the matched regex expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, extract

I want to extract the line above the regex matched expression.

```
Text 1
28-Apr
Text2
Text3
29-Apr
```

Output: `['Text 1', 'Text3']`

Comment: And the regexp value is?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to find the line numbers when your pattern occurs and then get the lines above, by subtracting 1 from the line numbers that were found. For example, if your pattern occurs on line 2 and 4, you need to get line 1 and 3. Please, look the example code below:

```
import re

string = """Text 1
28-Apr
Text2
Text3
29-Apr"""





pattern = '\d*\-\w*'
lines_number  = []
for m in re.finditer(pattern, string):
    start = m.start()
    lineno = string.count('\n', 0, start)


    lines_number.append(lineno)

for l in lines_number:
    print(string.split('\n')[l-1])
```